# path to (co)homology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

I want to understand (co)homology, but in the research I've done, it seems as though despite being 'birthed' within algebraic topology, its usefulness has allowed it to permeate throughout all branches of mathematics. As such, my question is:

What is the best avenue for somebody to get initial contact with it, i.e. algebraic topology, abstract algebra, manifold theory etc etc and what are the benefits and drawbacks of pursuing one entry point versus another? (for a 1st year graduate student)

Comment: A good path is to follow Ken Brown's book on cohomology.

Comment: The book 'Introduction to Manifolds' by Tu works toward de rham cohomology. It sets up things reasonably well for smooth manifolds, and works towards cochain complexes and the de rham complex for smooth manifolds.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Do you mean "Cohomology of Groups"?  Maybe just me but I found that book to be almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Hatcher is the canonical reference for the topological side. Bott and Tu is one of the best-written math books I've ever read, and it covers some of both the differential (i.e., via de Rham cohomology) and the algebraic side. Brown's book on cohomology is probably the canonical reference for introductory group cohomology, though the abstract nonsense involved in its motivation (namely, connecting $H^*_{\operatorname{group}}(G, \mathbb{Z})$ to $H^*_{\operatorname{top}}(K(1, G), \mathbb{Z})$ through resolutions) may not make sense without the previous references. For sheaf cohomology or cohomology as a derived functor, the usual introduction is through Hartshorne, but bear in mind that algebraic geometry has an incredibly steep learning curve.

Comment: Re Bott and Tu are you talking about Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology?  Or a different one?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Particularly, I don't recommend initial contact through Bott and Tu (that said, it is indeed well-written). I would recommend reading its preface though.